# Is there a better way to get numbers from dictionary (JSON data)?

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting

Assume I receive data in some JSON which is then parsed to dictionary using a native tool. Some of those values are numbers and naturally I will need to parse them, cast them into what I need in the application.

But the transition from `Any` to an actual number such as `Float`, `Int`, `Double` seems to be a bit messy. For instance if I expect a double but at some point server returns an integer my code will fail using:

```
let doubleValue = dictionary["key"] as! Double
```

So this will work when the item is `1.3` but will fail for `1`. To use a bit more concrete example we can use the following:

```
let myDictionary: [String: Any] = [
    "myNumber_int" : 1,
    "myNumber_float" : Float(1),
    "myNumber_cgFloat" : CGFloat(1),
    "myNumber_double" : 1.0
]

let numberInt1 = myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? Int // 1
let numberInt2 = myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? Float // nil
let numberInt3 = myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? CGFloat // nil
let numberInt4 = myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? Double // nil

let numberFloat1 = myDictionary["myNumber_float"] as? Int // nil
let numberFloat2 = myDictionary["myNumber_float"] as? Float // 1
let numberFloat3 = myDictionary["myNumber_float"] as? CGFloat // nil
let numberFloat4 = myDictionary["myNumber_float"] as? Double // nil

let numberCGFloat1 = myDictionary["myNumber_cgFloat"] as? Int // nil
let numberCGFloat2 = myDictionary["myNumber_cgFloat"] as? Float // nil
let numberCGFloat3 = myDictionary["myNumber_cgFloat"] as? CGFloat // 1
let numberCGFloat4 = myDictionary["myNumber_cgFloat"] as? Double // nil

let numberDouble1 = myDictionary["myNumber_double"] as? Int // nil
let numberDouble2 = myDictionary["myNumber_double"] as? Float // nil
let numberDouble3 = myDictionary["myNumber_double"] as? CGFloat // nil
let numberDouble4 = myDictionary["myNumber_double"] as? Double // 1
```

So for each type only 1 cast will actually work which is... well I would at least expect that `CGFloat` will be able to cast directly to `Double` or `Float`...

So my solution is using `NSNumber`:

```
let myNumbers: [CGFloat] = [
    CGFloat((myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0),
    CGFloat((myDictionary["myNumber_float"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0),
    CGFloat((myDictionary["myNumber_cgFloat"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0),
    CGFloat((myDictionary["myNumber_double"] as? NSNumber)?.floatValue ?? 0.0),
] // [1,1,1,1]
```

This naturally works but the code is pretty ugly for something as simple as this. But putting the code "ugliness" aside; can we not do similar without using Next Step? I mean `NSNumber` for something as seemingly trivial as this? I am missing something very obvious here, right?

Comment: Do you have to parse the JSON "using a native tool"? Can't you use `JSONDecoder` and `Codable`?

Comment: When you get `JSON` from somewhere integer values are `Int` and flowing point values are `Double`, period. If your parser creates more types use a better parser or consider Sweeper's suggestion.

Comment: @vadian I apologize if JSON thing confuses you but it is more of an example. But even if there are only integers and floats the issue persists.

Comment: If you create dictionaries with concrete types the types persist even if you declare the dictionary as `[String:Any]`. Again, received JSON has only two types. You can even `1` cast to `Double` (but of course not vice versa).

Comment: Well you should use `Any` in `Swift` language. `Any` is use for non objects or for all types in `Swift` so that `Int`, `Double`, `Float`, `Array`, `Dictionary` non of these are object. `AnyObject` is use for `Class` instance. One question if you don't know the type of value then why're you casting. Only `let numberInt2 = myDictionary["myNumber_int"]` will surely work.

Comment: @TheTiger well the point is that I do not know exact type of the input value but do the output value. For instance let's say I need `TimeInterval` but I sometimes get a `Float` and sometimes an `Int`. I would expect a tool that is able to convert any `Number` to be directly cast into `TimeInterval`. And for now this tool I see is `NSNumber` which seems a complete overkill and would be nice to avoid.

Comment: @MaticOblak `Swift` is a modern language and it knows which type of variable it has. So if you will use the variable as it is (without any type casting) it will give you correct result in calculation. type casting is extra headache in your case. `if dictionary["key"] is Int {}` or `print(type(of: dictionary["key"]))` this is the check if you still need to know the type.

Comment: @TheTiger Sure. That is completely understandable. What it seems is that Swift is missing an object that represents a number as already mentioned which may then be cast directly into any other number. In this case number being any primitive such as `Int`, `Float`, `Double` and even `CGFloat`, `TimeInterval`. Do you see where I am going with this?

Comment: @MaticOblak `TimeInterval` is `Double` itself. I know what you mean but in `Swift`  `Int, Double, Float, Array, Dictionary` are not objects and can be use as it is but in `Objective-C` only an object can be add into `Dictionary` or into `Array` so `Objective-C` needs `NSNumber` here which is not the case with `Swift`. I think so.

Comment: @TheTiger Well TimeInterval is type defined. And you type define stuff so you may change them later. We may in theory have 2 platforms where in one TimeInterval is a double and on other a float. I am looking for a safe solution to convert any "number" to a desired type. Are you saying this can not be done is Swift alone?

Comment: @MaticOblak What will you do after converting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171087/discussion-between-thetiger-and-matic-oblak).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
if let data = myDictionary as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let myNumber = data["myNumber_int"] as? Int
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Obviously there is no chance in casting the whole dictionary but the following does in fact work: `(myDictionary["myNumber_int"] as? AnyObject) as? Float`.

Comment: It is still pretty ugly and correct me if I am wrong but is `AnyObject` not designed for ObjectiveC bridge?

Comment: It will help you for nil handling also, if dictionary has no value... If you have array of Dictionary then create model to get structural data

Comment: It does work, I just tested it in a playground. I just dont fully understand why... whats the major different in this case between Any and AnyObject

Comment: I think I see what happens... By doing this you bridge to ObjectiveC which now automatically converts all the primitives to `NSNumber`. And now `NSNumber` is castable automatically to any primitive in Swift. I tested this by using `"myNumber_int" : NSNumber(value: 1.0)` in initial dictionary and the first part all returned values (all got casted correctly). So basically the first cast is done automatically for us in this case, nothing more. But I would like to avoid ObjectiveC and `NSNumber` if possible.

Comment: Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types. AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. String, Array, Dictionary are not classes for these we use any